# DownloadManager Class or use AsyncTask or service

Tags: android

My target device is a tablet running HoneyComb. I have a requirement where i should support simultaneous downloads of large video files using HTTP protocol. I am tending towards using the DownloadManager class since that allows me to pause/resume download tasks much more easily.

Would you recommend using DownloadManager class as well? Or if not, what are the limitations that i might have to deal with if i went this route?

TIA.

Comment: How to pause/resume download tasks easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DownloadManager

Pro:

1. Survives app restart and system reboot.
2. Can limit use over mobile networks (force wifi download only).

Con:

1. API is Level 9 - available only on Android 2.3+

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that `DownloadManager` can't save to internal storage - not sure if this is a problem for you or not?